# ERROR: This annotation is not applicable to target 'member function' in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dao

```
@Dao
interface CoinPriceInfoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM full_price_list ORDER BY lastupdate")
    fun getPriceList(): LiveData<List<CoinPriceInfo>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM full_price_list WHERE fromsymbol == :fSym LIMIT 1")
    fun getPriceInfoAboutCoin(fSym: String): LiveData<CoinPriceInfo>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertPriceList(priceList: List<CoinPriceInfo>)
}
```

I have an error for the first two Queries
What should I do?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwhrq.png)

Comment: Check imports, shoul be `import androidx.room.Query`

Comment: Thanks for trying to apply formatting, but please check if it's what you intended before submitting. There's a preview below the edit field.